# swift 3 Type 'Any' has no subscript members?

Tags: swift

i am getting Error parsing array of remote `JSON` , how to fix this issue ?

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

the code

```
do {
    if let json = response.result.value {
        //print("Server JSON Response : \(json)")

        if let countries = json["Countries"] as? [String: Any] {
            for country in countries {
                if let couname = country["countryname"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    country_names.append(couname)
                }

                if let coucode = country["code"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    country_codes.append(coucode)
                }

            }
        }


    }

  } catch let parseError {
       print("Hioston we have problem \(parseError) ")
}
```

Comment: ... and `countries` is `[[String:Any]]` and `countryname` is certainly not `[AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecast response as:

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{..}
```